# Database model for user ratings / reviews

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

What is the best way of modeling user reviews and scores in a database?

So the problem description would be the following:

> Imagine we had users who can rate items (give a score to an item), but
>   can also write reviews (with title, content, and also a score), and
>   maybe even submit more types of reviews, such as video reviews (with a
>   video and also a score for instance).
>
> Also, users can rate other user's reviews.

I've came up with the following EER diagram for this problem (does not include attributes nor the relationship between REVIEW and USER that would allow users to rate reviews):

[image: EER User Reviews]

In the design above, the different types of reviews (written review or video review) could be modeled by using inheritance, either in the same table using an attribute to differentiate between types or with a table per subclass.

An alternative to this design would be to consider the RATING table another type of review (one with no content or title, just a score), and use inheritance to model all the review types (scores, written reviews and video reviews). The problem I see with approach though is that I would need 2 relationships to allow users to rate reviews (one with written reviews and another one with video reviews), and would make it more difficult as well to retrieve all users reviews (written and video reviews).

Do you think one approach is better than the other (I'm leaning towards the first), or is there a better way of modeling this scenario?

Comment: You could have more than two types of reviews.  You could have aural reviews (podcasts).  I suspect the review type needs to be an attribute of Review.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That's a good observation. But with that in mind (the possibility of other types of reviews) I think the best would be to use a table per review type (inheritance using a table per class). By using an attribute type of review of a new review comes, we would need to alter the review table to acomodate all the attributes specific to that new review type. With a table per class, it would just be a new table in the hierarchy.